# Bootstrap navigation with dynamic heading

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

I have a reactJS application which uses Bootstrap to provide navigation for the site.  The container that sets up the menu looks like this:

```
<div className="container">
    <nav className="navbar navbar-light bg-light">
        <a className="navbar-brand" href="#">{this.state.planName}</a>
        <button className="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span className="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        {this.renderMenu()}
    </nav>
</div>
```

{this.renderMenu()} is where I dynamically place items into the menu structure and this works fine.

{this.state.planName} is a variable that contains a dynamic string which can be anywhere from 1 to 80 characters long.

My question is this:  When the length of {this.state.planName} is relatively short, the menu structure icon (the box with 3 horizontal lines) is generated at the top of the container and right justified in the container.  However, when the length of {this.state.planName} is relatively long, the menu structure icon bumps down and gets placed left justified in the container.

How can I force the menu structure icon to always be right justified in the container and only have {this.state.planName} wrap?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Since your `container` class likely has a `display: flex` style, it will try to give the minimum space necessary to display the entirety of each item inside its element. So when the content in `navbar-brand` gets too long, it pushes the `navbar-toggler` button outside the row so it has enough space to fit everything (flex). Your best option would really just be to set some sort of max-width on navbar-brand.

Try the following CSS:

```
.navbar-brand {
    max-width: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

Adjust `max-width` to your desired appearance.